# method call in mvc2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am a fresher and new to mvc2.I have a method in my model class dat will display a pie chart in a view. Now i have to call this method inside the index method of the controller. Can anyone guide me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the method in the model should give information to view in order to create the chart.

So:

```
Controller:
  get data for pie chart
  pass it to the view (return view(model))

Model 
  function to get the data for the pie chart

View
  display a pie chart with the data supplied by the controller.
```

Comment: Yes, you can create a repository class for it, though.

Comment: well I don't know how you generate the pie chart. But from this position I'd try to let the view generate the actual chart with the chart data supplied. What do you use to generate the pie chart? i.e. Google Chart API? Maybe http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart is usefull?